# How do I get my DataNavigator to count new number of rows after new row INSERT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

[image]

I am working on an application that creates and references the X,Y co-ordinates of a grid to an SQL server.

Mouse-tracked X-Y co-ordinates are used to search my SQL database and return the uniqueID number. If no X-Y co-ordinates are found, it then creates a new row with these co-ordinates.

Immediately after this I want it to query for the UniqueID number of the new row created and then I insert that number into the record box in the navigator (pictured as = 1). This then allows me to return the record.

**My issue is the "of 23" (record count). For some reason, this does not update when I add new rows to the server, but they do appear when I restart my programme or have the form .close and then .show again.**

My question is "How can I have the record count update without requiring a restart?"

```
Private Sub SearchSQL()

    SQL.AddParam("@XLocation", VCurrentLocationX)
    SQL.AddParam("@YLocation", VCurrentLocationY)

    SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Mapper_Table WHERE [X] = @XLocation AND [Y] = @YLocation;")

    Try
        Locations.XLocation.Text = SQL.DBDT.Rows(0).Item("X").ToString
        Locations.YLocation.Text = SQL.DBDT.Rows(0).Item("Y").ToString
        Locations.Current.Text = SQL.DBDT.Rows(0).Item("UniqueID")

    Catch ex As Exception

        'If no row exists, create it 
        InsertXY()

    End Try

    'Take UniqueID and search with it in Data Navigator ("Current")
    Locations.Current.Focus()
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
    Locations.LocationTextBox.Focus()

    'Me.Focus()
    'Causes Visual Glitch


End Sub



Private Sub InsertXY()

    'Add SQL Parameters and run the Commands

    SQL.AddParam("@XLocation", VCurrentLocationX)
    SQL.AddParam("@YLocation", VCurrentLocationY)

    SQL.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO Mapper_table ([X],[Y]) " &
                 "VALUES (@XLocation,@YLocation);", True)

    'Report and Abort
    If SQL.HasException(True) Then Exit Sub



    'MsgBox("A New Location has been added!")

    'If SQL.DBDT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    'Dim r As DataRow = SQL.DBDT.Rows(0)
    'MsgBox(r("LastID").ToString)
    'End If


End Sub

 'Execute Query Sub
Public Sub ExecQuery(query As String, Optional ReturnIdentity As Boolean = False)
    'RESET Query Stat's
    RecordCount = 0
    Exception = ""

    Try
        DBCon.Open()

        'Create Database Command
        DBCmd = New SqlCommand(query, DBCon)

        'Load Parameters into Database Command
        Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))

        'Clear Parameters before Running Next Query
        Params.Clear()

        'Execute Command & Fill Dataset
        DBDT = New DataTable
        DBDA = New SqlDataAdapter(DBCmd)
        RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)

        If ReturnIdentity = True Then
            Dim ReturnQuery As String = "SELECT @@IDENTITY As LastID"
            DBCmd = New SqlCommand(ReturnQuery, DBCon)
            DBDT = New DataTable
            DBDA = New SqlDataAdapter(DBCmd)
            RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        'Capture Error
        Exception = "ExecQuery Error: " & vbNewLine & ex.Message


    Finally
        'Close Connection
        If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()

    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this bit of code just after I generated the new row...

```
'Refresh Number of Rows on Record
    Locations.Mapper_TableBindingSource.Filter = Nothing
    Locations.Mapper_TableTableAdapter.Fill(Locations.ExcelDMDataSet.Mapper_Table)
```

Comment: Hi Arya, yes; I just had to wait two days.